# how to add mutiple values to jquery code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created the code to show a div only once a category is selected from a dropdown,
I have made the div `display:none` in css and showed it in jquery using this code and its working,

```
$(' select[name=catId]').change(function(e){
      if ($(' select[name=catId]').val() == '32'){
        $('#photo-upload').hide();
      }else{
        $('#photo-upload').show();
      }
    });
```

But this way its working for the option value 32 , but i want it to work for many values,
I have tried like this but it dont work

```
 $(' select[name=catId]').change(function(e){
          if ($(' select[name=catId]').val() == '32' '45' 67' 89' 122'){
            $('#photo-upload').hide();
          }else{
            $('#photo-upload').show();
          }
        });
```

Please guide me on how to make it hide for the other values too not just 32 , now its working for me for just one value.

UPDATE:
This is my html structure

```
<select name="catId" id="catId">
    <option value="1">England</option>
    <option value="2">Russia</option>
    <option value="3">Antartika</option>
    <option value="4">Maldives</option>
    <option value="32">Alaska</option>
    <option value="45">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="67">Georgia</option>
    <option value="89">Honduras</option>
    <option value="7">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="8">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="122">Germany</option>
</select>
<div id="photo-upload">photo uploader here</div>
```

Here is the fidlle demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/Bk54E/

Comment: Show us the html structure.. And provide some more useful info regarding your question.. Because it seems unclear..

Comment: means you want if any of `'32' '45' 67' 89' 122'` is equal to val then it should hide. am I right?

Comment: @mritunjay Yes correct

Comment: I've given an answer based on what I do for these kind of situations

Comment: here is the html structure http://jsfiddle.net/Bk54E/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bk54E/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OR operator like this

```
$("select[name='catId']").change(function(e){

    var res = $(this).find("option:selected").val() ;

    if (res == '32' || res == '45' || res == '67' || res == '89' || res == '122'){

         $('#photo-upload').hide();

      }else{

          $('#photo-upload').show();

      }
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bk54E/1/)

Comment: `$(this).find("option:selection").val();` === `this.value`

Comment: @sudharsan  this worked perfectly!   one small problem - now when i the page load the photo uploader is not showing even tough its set to england option value"1"  which should show it, any idea how can i make it show even when the page is first loaded?

Comment: Just add one line before it - $('#photo-upload').show();

Answer (score 0):

use

use **[inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)** in jquery

```
$.inArray( $(' select[name=catId]').val(), [ '32', '45', '67', '89', '122' ] );
```

OR

```
 $.inArray( this.value , [ '32', '45', '67', '89', '122' ] );
```

Your JS code will be look

```
$("select[name='catId']").change(function(){
       if( $.inArray(this.value, ['32', '45', '67', '89', '122' ] )!=-1){
            $('#photo-upload').hide();
          }else{
            $('#photo-upload').show();
          }
        });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w9kqy/27/)

Comment: Thank for the answer , im new to jquery, can you write me this code integrated with mine, because im not sure where to add it

Comment: Thank this works on your demo but in mine it dont, my options are like this  <option value="32">OPTION NAME HERE</option>   Is this making the problem?  Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Better use something like this.

```
if(['32', '45', '67', '89', '122'].indexOf($(' select[name=catId]').val())>-1){
     //hide
}
```

So basically if any of these will be equal to `select's value` condition will be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
var selValue = ['32', '45', '67', '89', '122'];

if ($(' select[name=catId]').val() == $.inArray(this.value, selValue){
```

Comment: i also tried this but didnt work, could you check my html maybe my html is dfferent hers the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bk54E/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this inArray in jquery built in function

```
<html>
    <body>

        <select name="category">
          <option value="31">Volvo</option>
          <option value="32">Saab</option>
          <option value="33">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="34">Audi</option>
        </select> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
<html>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var category1 =[31,32];
        var category2 =['33'];
        var category3 =['34']
        $('select[name=category]').change(function(){

            var selectedValue = $('select[name=category]').val();
            if($.inArray(selectedValue,category1) != -1)  {
                alert('hey u have selected category 1');
            }else if($.inArray(selectedValue,category2) != -1)  {
                alert('hey u have selected category 2');
            }else if($.inArray(selectedValue,category3) != -1)  {
                alert('hey u have selected category 3');
            }else{
                alert('invalid category');
            }

        });

    });
    </script>
```

For more information on array manipulation please get in over here
[How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)